# Rigid registration of two 3d point clouds in R

Tags: r, registration, point-clouds

I'd like to perform a rigid registration of two point clouds in R. Both clouds contain an identical number of coordinates and have been subsampled from two different scanned objects. In order to perform some statistics on the deviation between both clouds, I have to translocate and rotate one in such a way that it resembles the second cloud. However, the points of both clouds are most likely not homologous. Thus, a principal component analysis isn't wise. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Found a simple solution. I've used the 'ipcmat' function from the R 'Morph' package.